# Видео с youtube в RecycleView

Tags: java, android, recyclerview

Как вывести видео с youtube в RecycleView?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Подключить библиотеку для youtube.
2. Создать адаптер для RecyclerView
3. Отобразить там видео каким-то из множества способов.

Более подробно ответить нельзя т.к. ваш вопрос слишком общий.